# Use print button in modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I am designing a receipt generator for client. The client add payment receipt using add button and after they click on submit they have option to convert it to pdf or print this. However since my form contains texxt field . It not printing it properly and only outputting the filled content.I tried using window.print but its dispalying boxes as well. Not sure how to proceed. below is the code:

I used the javascript but is unable to add classes

```
 $('button[name="e_subPrint"]').click(function(){
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
    var html = getPrintHtml("e_print");
    mywindow.document.write(html);

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    });

    function getPrintHtml(print){
        var center = $('#'+print +' input[name="center"]').val();
        var dated = $('#'+print +' input[name="dated"]').val();
        var payment = $('#'+print +' input[name="payment"]').val();
        var studname = $('#'+print +' input[name="studname"]').val();
        var cnum = $('#'+print +' input[name="cnum"]').val();
        var pnum = $('#'+print +' input[name="pnum"]').val();
        var sum = $('#'+print +' input[name="sum"]').val();
        var amt = $('#'+print +' input[name="amt"]').val();
        var chnum = $('#'+print +' input[name="chnum"]').val();
        var chdate = $('#'+print +' input[name="chdate"]').val();
        var chbank = $('#'+print +' input[name="chbank"]').val();
        var course = $('#'+print +' input[name="course"]').val();
        var tfees = $('#'+print +' input[name="tfees"]').val();
        var sgst = $('#'+print +' input[name="sgst"]').val();
        var cgst = $('#'+print +' input[name="cgst"]').val();
        var gtotal = $('#'+print +' input[name="gtotal"]').val();

        var html = "<html><table>\n\
                    <tr><td>CENTER: </td><td>"+center+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>DATED: </td><td>"+dated+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>PAYMENT: </td><td>"+payment+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>STUDENT NAME: </td><td>"+studname+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>CONTACT NUMBER: </td><td>"+cnum+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>PARENTAL CONTACT: </td><td>"+pnum+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>TOTAL AMOUNT: </td><td>"+amt+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>CHEQUE NUMBER: </td><td>"+chnum+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>CHEQUE DATE: </td><td>"+chdate+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>CHEQUE BANK: </td><td>"+chbank+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>COURSE: </td><td>"+course+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>TUITION FEES: </td><td>"+tfees+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>SGST: </td><td>"+sgst+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>CGST: </td><td>"+cgst+"</td></tr>\n\
                    <tr><td>GRAND TOTAL: </td><td>"+gtotal+"</td></tr>\n\
                    \n\
                    </table></html>";

        return html;
    }
});
```

This the HTMl

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Receipt</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form method="post" action="controller/pdf.php">
                            <div id="print">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                        <img src="asset/logo.png" alt="Edumentor">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <p style="font-size:15px;">Head Office: 80 Defence Enclave Delhi-110092
                                            <br>
                                            Tel : +91 9650499917,9650499918  web:wwww.edumentor.co.in
                                            <br>
                                            GST No.07AACCE9830DIZS   
                                        </p>
                                        <br>
                                        <p><strong>Receipt Number:</strong>
                                            <?php
                                            $val = getReceiptNum();
                                            echo $val;
                                            ?>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <br>
                                <div id="values">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-inline">
                                            <div style="text-align:right;" class="col-sm-8">
                                                <label for="centre">Centre: </label>
                                                <input name="center" id="centre" type="text" class="form-control" name="centre"> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <label for="date">Dated:</label>
                                                <input id="dated" name="dated" type="date" class="form-control" name="date">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <br>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <label for="pcentre">Payment Centre:</label>
                                                <input name="payment" id="payment" type="text" class="form-control" name="pcentre">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <br>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <label for="stuname">Student Name:</label>
                                                <input name="studname" id="stuname" type="text" class="form-control" name="stuname">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <br>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-inline">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    <label for ="stucont">Contact Number:</label>
                                                    <input name="cnum" id="cnum" type="text" class="form-control" name="stucont">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    <label for="stupcont">Parental Contact:</label>
                                                    <input name="pnum" id="pnum" type="text" class="form-control" name="stupcont">
                                                </div>
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                                        <tbody>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                                        <label for="sfees">Sum of Rupees(In Words)</label>
                                                        <input name="sum" id="sum" type="text" class="form-control" name="sfees" size="30">
                                                    </div>  
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                                        <label for="">Total Amount :</label>
                                                        <input name="amt" id="amt" type="number" name="snumfees" class="form-control" size="10" placeholder="Enter Amount">
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>   
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                        <label>Paid by: </label>
                                                        <label class="radio-inline"><input id="cash" value="cash" type="radio" name="optradio">Cash</label>
                                                        <label class="radio-inline"><input id="cheque" type="radio" value="cheque" name="optradio">Cheque</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                        <input name="chnum" id="chnum" type="text" name="cheqno" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter cheque number">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                        <input name="chdate" id="chdate" type="date" name="cheqdate" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter cheque date">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                        <input name="chbank" id="chbank" type="text" name="cheqbank" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter cheque bank">
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>


                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                                        <label for="cname">Course Name:</label>
                                                        <input name="course" id="course" type="text" name="cname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Course name">
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                                        <label for="tutfees">Tution Fees:</label>
                                                        <input name="tfees" id="tfees" type="text" name="tutfees" class="form-control" readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                                        <label for="stax">SGST:</label>
                                                        <input name="sgst" id="sgst" type="number" name="stax" class="form-control" readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                                        <label for="ctax">CGST:</label>
                                                        <input name="cgst" id="cgst" type="number" name="ctax" class="form-control" readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                                        <label for="gtfees">Grand Total:</label>
                                                        <input name="gtotal" readonly id="gtotal" type="number" name="gtfees" placeholder="Enter total fees" class="form-control">
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                                <br>
                                <div><p><strong>Terms and Condition:</strong></p>
                                    <br>
                                    <p style="font-size:small; width:120%;margin-top:-4%;">
                                        1.Any fees once paid shall not be refunded under any circumstances.<br>
                                        2.We do not disclose any personal information of student before or after the announcement of the result.<br>
                                        3.In case the cheque bounces, the student is liable to pay ₹500/- extra and deposit whole amount in cash within next 24-48 hours.<br>
                                        4.In case of delay of installment from the due date, penalty @ ₹250/- per day will be charged from the student.<br>
                                        5.Tution fee inclusive of GST.<br>
                                        6.All disputes are subject to exclusive juridsiction of Delhi Courts only.<br>
                                        7.All cheque are to be drawn in favour of '<strong>Edumentor Educational Services Pvt. Ltd</strong>.'
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                I agree to the above terms and conditions
                                <br><br><br><br><br>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <label>Parents/Student Signature</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="text-align:right;" class="col-md-4">
                                        <label>Authorised Signatory</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="pdf" id="pdf" value="Export To Pdf"/>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnPrint" name="subPrint">PRINT</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="js:window.print()">print modal content</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download printThis.js from the following link and include it in your html: https://github.com/jasonday/printThis/blob/0a7f799693af8a8303bf0b8df0efc80c2694af81/printThis.js

Wrap the content you want to print with the following div. Everything outside of this div will not be printed.

```
<div id="modalDiv">
    ..content to print..
</div>
```

Call the following jquery to print all the content including the content that is not viewable. You may include your css files in an array if you have multiple css files.

```
$("#modalDiv").printThis({ 
    debug: false,              
    importCSS: true,             
    importStyle: true,         
    printContainer: true,       
    loadCSS: "../css/style.css", 
    pageTitle: "My Modal",             
    removeInline: false,        
    printDelay: 333,            
    header: null,             
    formValues: true          
});
```